# App crashes when signing with Facebook while Facebook App installed on Android Device

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, samsung-mobile

I develop an App that allow user to sign in with their Facebook account.

It works fine until last week.

Now it crash when user try to sign in with their Facebook, when the Facebook App is installed on the device.

And it works just fine when there's no Facebook app installed.

why is it happen ? Did facebook changed their API lately?

I believe the problem has something to do with recent lolipop upgrade that force intent to be explicit. That is supported by the stack trace

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.google/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Service Intent must be explicit: Intent** { act=com.facebook.platform.PLATFORM_SERVICE cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] }
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2958)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.facebook.platform.PLATFORM_SERVICE cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] }
    at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1745)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1844)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1822)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
    at com.facebook.GetTokenClient.start(GetTokenClient.java:62)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient.java:535)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:214)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:193)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.authorize(AuthorizationClient.java:121)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:102)
    at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:113)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1241)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6063)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.facebook.platform.PLATFORM_SERVICE cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] }
    at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1745)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1844)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1822)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
    at com.facebook.GetTokenClient.start(GetTokenClient.java:62)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient.java:535)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:214)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:193)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.authorize(AuthorizationClient.java:121)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:102)
    at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:113)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1241)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6063)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

Log Cat:

```
    java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
    at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.enableConnectionGC(AbstractConnPool.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.createConnectionPool(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.<init>(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:98)
    at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.getHttpClient(HttpRequest.java:214)
    at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:141)
    at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:225)
    at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:179)
    at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
    at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
```

This is the actual code

```
public void loginFacebook(){
    Session session = new Session(context);
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
    if (fragment != null) {
        openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(fragment);
    } else if (context instanceof Activity) {
        openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity)context);
    }

    if (openRequest != null) {
        openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
        openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday"));
        openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);

        session.openForRead(openRequest);
    }
}
```

I suspected it happens because of this

```
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/04/28/april-30-migration/

--------- beginning of main
05-13 22:16:52.708 I/SensorManager( 5740): registerListenerImpl() [Sensor: LGE Orientation Sensor, Rate: 200000, SensorEventListener: com.google.MySensorManager$1@6c83602] bycom.google.MySensorManager.getSensor():43
05-13 22:16:56.140 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:16:56.204 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:16:56.217 I/SensorManager( 5740): removeAllSensors() [Sensor: LGE Orientation Sensor] bycom.google.MySensorManager.unregisterListener():132
05-13 22:16:56.379 I/SensorManager( 5740): registerListenerImpl() [Sensor: LGE Orientation Sensor, Rate: 200000, SensorEventListener: com.google.MySensorManager$1@28004a85] bycom.google.MySensorManager.getSensor():43
05-13 22:16:56.407 D/URL     ( 5740): http://www.listaboutplaces.com/ocr/Catalog/api/v2/GetCatalog.ashx?keyword=&distance=5000&lat=-7.2757458&long=112.7833469&howmany=20&startfrom=0&maxbiz=5&deviceid=196c72a543837635&latitude=-7.2757458&longitude=112.7833469&tk=35fad0d79639371225369f3466dd7603
05-13 22:16:56.419 I/CliptrayUtils( 5740): CliptrayUtils created!! mTextView = android.widget.EditText{2032f839 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0700e8 app:id/editSearchBar}
05-13 22:16:56.435 D/BubblePopupHelper( 5740): isShowingBubblePopup : false
05-13 22:16:56.438 I/CliptrayUtils( 5740): CliptrayUtils created!! mTextView = android.widget.EditText{cf3b718 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0700e8 app:id/editSearchBar}
05-13 22:16:56.466 D/BubblePopupHelper( 5740): isShowingBubblePopup : false
05-13 22:16:56.466 D/BubblePopupHelper( 5740): isShowingBubblePopup : false
05-13 22:16:56.466 D/BubblePopupHelper( 5740): isShowingBubblePopup : false
05-13 22:16:56.466 D/BubblePopupHelper( 5740): isShowingBubblePopup : false
05-13 22:16:58.127 I/art     ( 5740): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7(128B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 94MB/94MB, paused 5.004ms total 14.012ms
05-13 22:16:59.314 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:16:59.465 D/BubblePopupHelper( 5740): isShowingBubblePopup : false
05-13 22:16:59.652 D/skia    ( 5740): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
05-13 22:16:59.836 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:16:59.836 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: DOWN vectorVelocity:2271 signal:1
05-13 22:17:00.538 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:00.635 D/BubblePopupHelper( 5740): isShowingBubblePopup : false
05-13 22:17:00.646 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:00.646 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-6690 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:00.725 D/skia    ( 5740): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
05-13 22:17:00.917 D/skia    ( 5740): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
05-13 22:17:01.232 D/skia    ( 5740): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
05-13 22:17:01.907 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:01.985 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:01.985 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-8157 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:02.243 D/skia    ( 5740): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
05-13 22:17:02.423 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:02.615 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:03.285 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:03.365 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:03.365 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-5929 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:04.646 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:04.734 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:04.735 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-5980 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:05.132 D/skia    ( 5740): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
05-13 22:17:05.340 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:05.841 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:05.841 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-3063 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:05.845 D/BubblePopupHelper( 5740): isShowingBubblePopup : false
05-13 22:17:06.439 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:06.561 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:06.561 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-4992 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:07.248 D/skia    ( 5740): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
05-13 22:17:08.719 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:08.839 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:08.839 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-4422 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:09.039 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:09.208 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:09.208 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: DOWN vectorVelocity:1292 signal:1
05-13 22:17:10.676 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:10.903 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:15.809 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:15.959 D/BubblePopupHelper( 5740): isShowingBubblePopup : false
05-13 22:17:15.960 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:15.960 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-3968 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:16.738 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:16.832 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:16.832 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-4285 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:17.419 D/skia    ( 5740): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
05-13 22:17:17.509 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:17.609 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:17.609 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-6129 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:18.316 D/skia    ( 5740): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
05-13 22:17:18.708 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:19.461 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:20.378 D/skia    ( 5740): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
05-13 22:17:20.723 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:20.831 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:20.831 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-5394 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:22.509 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:22.725 D/URL     ( 5740): http://www.listaboutplaces.com/ocr/Catalog/api/v2/GetCatalog.ashx?keyword=&distance=5000&lat=-7.2757458&long=112.7833469&howmany=20&startfrom=20&maxbiz=5&deviceid=196c72a543837635&latitude=-7.2757458&longitude=112.7833469&tk=35fad0d79639371225369f3466dd7603
05-13 22:17:22.728 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:22.728 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:-520 signal:-1
05-13 22:17:23.210 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:23.368 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:23.368 W/TouchFlickNoti( 5740): CAPP_TOUCH_FLICK: UP vectorVelocity:0 signal:0
05-13 22:17:24.518 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:24.604 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:24.611 I/SensorManager( 5740): removeAllSensors() [Sensor: LGE Orientation Sensor] bycom.google.MySensorManager.unregisterListener():132
05-13 22:17:24.617 D/BubblePopupHelper( 5740): isShowingBubblePopup : false
05-13 22:17:26.218 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:26.309 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:27.223 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:27.313 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:28.054 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:28.119 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:29.771 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-13 22:17:29.818 I/ViewRootImpl( 5740): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-13 22:17:29.841 I/Timeline( 5740): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.google time:30161984
05-13 22:17:29.875 D/ContextHelper( 5740): convertTheme. context->name=com.google themeResourceId=2131492978
05-13 22:17:29.911 D/AndroidRuntime( 5740): Shutting down VM
05-13 22:17:29.918 E/ACRA    ( 5740): ACRA caught a RuntimeException exception for com.google. Building report.
05-13 22:17:29.918 D/ACRA    ( 5740): Using custom Report Fields
05-13 22:17:29.954 I/ACRA    ( 5740): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
05-13 22:17:30.010 D/ACRA    ( 5740): Retrieving logcat output...
```

Comment: Looks like you are using an [old](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.5/class/Session/) SDK implementation, try updating your SDK and use the new APIs [first](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3).

Comment: The usefulness of these comments is shocking ^^^^